# Ansible Pull mulptiple repo

Tags: if-statement, ansible

I want to pull multiple repositories via ansible playbook but with if condition matches,

```
tasks:
    - name: pull from git abc/123
      git:
        repo: git@gitlab.com:xyz.git
        dest: var/www/abc/123
        update: yes
        version: $sprint_name

tasks:
    - name: pull from git abc/234 
      git:
        repo: git@gitlab.com:xyz.git
        dest: /var/www/234
        update: yes
        version: $sprint_name
```

Now here I want to pass "123" or "234" as variable and if user want to pull only "123" or only "234" user should be able to do it

Comment: Please, format the question properly and make it readable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want the user to make choices during playbook runtime, by typing in some information that will alter the playbook's execution, you can use the `vars_prompt` section.

You will get his response to a variable and with a `when` section in your tasks you can control which tasks to run.

[documentation here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html)

Comment: Glad to hear that @rohitkulkarni! perhaps you can mark the question answered, so people who browse for unanswered questions won't stumble on this one.